# How to do authorization in an authentication microservice?

Tags: node.js, authentication, authorization, token, microservices

I am developing an auth service (NodeJS) that handles authentication and authorization.

I have two endpoints:

> **`/auth-token`**
>
> Client apps can fetch auth tokens (JSON web tokens) via POST. The auth service stores each generated JSON web token in its database.
>
> **`/authorize`**
>
> Other services within the SOA will verify auth tokens (from Authorization headers) at this endpoint.

#### Implementation of `/authorize`

I am not sure about the logic behind the `/authorize` endpoint.

#### Method I

1. Get auth token from `Authorization` header
2. Do a DB lookup of the token and see if it exists and not expired

#### Method II

1. Have a user database within the auth service and store all user info coming to `/auth-token` endpoint.
2. During authorization via `/authorize`, if the token has not expired, decode the token.
3. Get the user info and do a DB lookup to see if they
   exist in the user db.

Or some other way. Please let me know.

Comment: Why do you need to check for user existence?

Comment: Not sure. Most tutorials I looked through did decode the token, got the user info, and did user lookups in DB. Let me know if you think it is wrong (or not necessary for my token service). From my limited experience building auth-related stuff from the ground up, those two methods are the ones I could think of. Please suggest better ways.